# Total number of permutations of elements following a set of rules

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Consider the following elements: $s, a, b, \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \beta_1, \beta_2$ and the corresponding rules:

- $s$ is always the first element.
- $a$ must always be in front of $\alpha_i, i = 1, 2, 3$.
- $b$ must always be in front of $\beta_j, j = 1, 2$.

How many (permissible) permutations are there of this set of elements? How can this be generalized to a setting where there are more "a's and b's", i.e., more elements which must occur before a specific set of other elements?

---

What I know so far:

- For $a$, there are $|\{ \alpha_i : i = 1, 2, 3 \}| ! = 3! = 6$ permutations for its dependent elements.
- For $b$, there are therefore $2! = 2$ permutations for its dependent elements.

How can I put this together though to form permutations of all elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the general problem where you permute elements of $\Sigma = \{a_1,\ldots,a_n,\alpha_{1,1},\ldots,\alpha_{1,m_1},\alpha_{2,1},\ldots,\alpha_{2,m_2},\ldots,\alpha_{n,1},\ldots,\alpha_{n,m_n}\}$ where for each $i$, $a_i$ must be in front of all the $\alpha_{i,j}$. Let $P$ be the set of admissible permutations and $M = \sum_{i = 1}^n (m_i + 1)$. Let,
$$
\varphi : \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} P \times \prod_{i = 1}^n [\![0,m_i]\!] & \rightarrow & \mathcal{S}_M \\ \left(\sigma,j_1,\ldots,j_n\right) & \mapsto & \tilde{\sigma} \end{array}\right.,
$$
where $\tilde{\sigma}$ is what you obtain when you exchange $a_i$ and $\alpha_{i,j_i}$ in $\sigma$ (or doing nothing if $j_i = 0$). $\varphi$ is a bijection whose inverse is,
$$
\varphi^{-1} : \left\{\begin{array}{rcl} \mathcal{S}_M & \rightarrow & P \times \prod_{i = 1}^n [\![0,m_i]\!] \\ \tilde{\sigma} & \mapsto & \left(\sigma,j_1,\ldots,j_n\right) \end{array}\right.,
$$
where $\sigma$ is obtained by exchanging, in $\tilde{\sigma}$, each $a_i$ with the $\alpha_{i,j}$ that is in first position among the $(a_i,\alpha_{i,1},\ldots,\alpha_{i,m_i})$ and by setting $j_i = j$ (or $j_i = 0$ if $a_i$ was already the first of the list). We deduce that,
$$
|P| = \frac{\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n (m_i + 1)\right)!}{\prod_{i = 1}^n (m_i + 1)}.
$$
In your case, $|P| = \frac{(3 + 4)!}{3 \cdot 4} = 420$.

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1:**  There is one way to place $s$ in the first position.  That leaves seven elements to arrange.  Choose four of the remaining seven positions in which to place the elements $a, \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$.  The $a$ must be placed in the first of those positions.  As you observed, there are $3!$ ways to arrange $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ in the remaining three of those four positions.  That leaves three positions for $b, \beta_1, \beta_2$.  The $b$ must be placed in the first of those three positions.  As you observed, there are $2!$ ways to arrange $\beta_1, \beta_2$ in the remaining two positions.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{7}{4}3!2!$$
admissible arrangements.

**Method 2:**  Since $s$ must be in the first position, there are seven elements to arrange.  If there were no restrictions, we could arrange them in $7!$ ways.  By symmetry, in $1/4$ of these arrangements, $a$ precedes $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$.  By symmetry, in $1/3$ of these arrangements, $b$ precedes $b, \beta_1, \beta_2$.  Hence, the number of admissible arrangements is
$$\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{4} \cdot 7!$$

Answer (score 2):

Forget invariant $s$,
and in a row of $7$ discs, randomly punch $3$ holes for $b,{\beta_1,\beta_2}\quad\bullet\bullet\circ\bullet\circ\bullet\circ$

With the $a's$ preceding all $\alpha's$ and $b's$ preceding all $\beta's$,

# of valid  permutations $= \binom73 2!3! = 420$

and to generalise, if there are $m \;\alpha's,\;n\;\beta's$

# of valid permutations $=\dbinom{m+n+2}{n+1}m!n!$

which simplifies to $\dfrac{m+n+2)!}{(m+1)(n+1)}$

and  if we call $(m+1), (n+1)$ as $A,B$  to

$\dfrac{(A+B)!}{AB},$ extendable to $\dfrac{(A+B+C+..)!}{ABC..}$